# New to Rails trying to pass month and year from a form to a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I've completed Hartl's Rails Tutorial and am now working on a project that uses the simple_calendar gem.

I want to add a dropdown to allow users to quickly navigate to a specific month and year without having to click the "next" link multiple times.

So far I have managed to create the dropdown form but I can't figure out how to set up the controller to get the url with the form parameters on submit.

This is in the partial I created that renders at the top of the monthview calendar:

```
<%= form_with do |form|  %>
  <%= select_month( Time.now, {:field_name => 'month', :id => 'month'} ) %>
  <%= select_year( Date.today, {:start_year => Time.now.year,:end_year => Time.now.year+3} ,{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'year'} ) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Go", :id=>"button", :class=>"date-button", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone explain how I can write the controller code to pass those parameters so that the user goes to a link like https://mycalendar.com/calendar?year=2021&month=june

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would prefer to use https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select here

Answer (score 0):

You can read the parameters directly

```
<%= form_with do |form|  %>
  <%= select_month( params[:month].present? ? Date.strptime(params[:month], '%B') : Time.now, {:field_name => 'month', :id => 'month'} ) %>
  <%= select_year( params[:year].present? ? Date.strptime(params[:year], '%y') : Date.today, {:start_year => Time.now.year,:end_year => Time.now.year+3} ,{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'year'} ) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Go", :id=>"button", :class=>"date-button", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

But you have to add a checking for invalid date/parameters, so better do the parsing in the controller side

Answer (score 0):

You can grab parameters sent to a controller via `params[:parameter]`. This works for both GET and POST requests. In a GET request these parameters are passed through the url, ie. `/calendar?year=2021&month=june`, whereas in a POST request they are passed in a formBody object.

One of the best things to do in Rails is to look at your console when a request is made. It will tell you the route, controller, action, and parameters in the log.

For a GET request you might use the method below to get the parameters.

```
# controller
def calendar
  year = params[:year]
  month = params[:month]
end
```

Generally a form would be sent via a PUT (create) or PATCH (update) request (known together as POST). In that case you might have a model object that the form fields would be stored in, and you would grab the parameters through a sanitization procedure. This sanitization is very important to ensure malicious code isn't passed through to your database.

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  ...
end

private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:month, :year, :title)
  end
```

Your form_with might need a `url: '/calendar'` and even a `method: :get` to turn it into a GET request and send it to the correct route.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. Much appreciated!